# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' after create-t3-app bootstrap

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, t3

I ran the command `npm create t3-app@latest` to bootstrap a new next.js app. When I rant the command `npm run dev` to run the app, I got the following syntax error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='`.

It also printed a bunch of compiled looking code to my console.

I tried deleting the app and going through the application flow again. I also tried deleting my node_modules. Neither of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to upgrade node to a newer version on my local. I was an older version and bumping to v16.17.0 fixed the issue and made `npm run dev` work.

Comment: You probably should update further, because node 16 will be out of maintenance in a few month. The current LTS (and recommended) version is node 18.